# layoutwidth fill_parent widget in actionLayout not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Menu Main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:gpsproship="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/menu_dieuhuongactivity">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_dieuhuongactivity_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    gpsproship:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    gpsproship:actionLayout="@layout/search_layout"/>
</menu>
```

SearchLayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_search"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But when i run, edittext id txt_search width not fill... this ia smaill width
[image]

Comment: `fill_parent` is depreciated, use `match_parent` instead.

Comment: i have tried match_parent and nothing change happed

Comment: I know, just saying use it instead of fill in future. About the problem: add         `gpsproship:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"` as the property of the search menu item & remove `gpsproship:actionLayout="@layout/search_layout"`.  I am using it and it works just fine. Hope it helps.

Comment: i know SearchView but i don't find any solution to real filter data when type in searchview.
all in one activity..no start acitivy for display result

Comment: What are you searching via this? Must be having some sort of adapter, no?

Answer (score 1):

Use RelativeLayout  work with me

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:id="@+id/visibility_search_edit_text"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="search_title"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/your_layout_name"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom" />
```

The difference is showAsAction property and actionlayout